# Dynamic paths in react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I am trying to migrate my website from traditional web app approach to react based app. In this process I am stuck with a problem related to urls. In my website, on server side I use **Url Rewrite** feature to map urls to their correct controller. But I am not able to figure out how to handle this thing in react router. My current, react router code looks like this

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
    <Route path="/black-forest" component={Product}/>
    <Route path="/cakes" component={ProductList}/>
</BrowserRouter>
```

This code I have written for building a prototype. But ideally there are many different urls which can point to `ProductList` component. Similarly there are many urls which can point to `Product` component.

For e.g,
Following urls points to `ProductList` component

 `- http://www.example.com/best-cakes-in-australia
 - http://www.example.com/cake-delivery-in-india
 - http://www.example.com/flowers-delivery-in-canada`

At a gross level I have around 10,000 such urls which are created using server side `UrlRewrite` hence they follow no specific pattern. These url are mostly going to point towards either `ProductList` or `Product` component.

How can I create path for all these urls in my react router config? Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Would this work for you? You have a route for example `<Route path="/product-list/:products" component={ProductList}/>` that handles links like `http://www.example.com/product-list/best-cakes-in-australia` and you could display what you need based on the value of `:products`

Comment: If a user wants to see best cakes in australia, in that case user will see `http://www.example.com/product-list/best-cakes-in-australia` instead of `http://www.example.com/best-cakes-in-australia` right? No, this won't work as it will create new url, and maintaining current urls is critical from SEO standpoint

Comment: Ok so it still seems usable to me... just look for params.products === 781 when you need to show best cakes in australia and extrapolate from there.

Comment: @KyleRichardson I don't really understood how you mean to do it? Could you please provide more details?

Comment: Ok I will have to ask you a few questions possibly. You say the routes follow no specific pattern. Does that mean that urls that need to display the product-list will not have product-list in their url? If they are all `http://www.example.com/product-list/:parameter` Then in your `ProductList` component you can use the `this.props.params.product` value and display the proper data based on that param.product value.

Comment: If I can have urls like `http://www.example.com/product-list/:parameter` then there is no issue as parameter can hold dynamic value. But my urls are like what I gave in example in question above. It is because of SEO, and I can't really change them just to suit for `react` needs

Comment: Gotcha, well as far as I know ( hope I'm wrong! ) but it seems like you're in for some typing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149957/discussion-between-abhi-and-kyle-richardson).

Comment: @gravityplanx Well it can happen, take example of a blog where post title also makes post url. These urls won't follow any pattern. Including all paths is obviously an option. But it doesn't seems right to me, because if the urls keep growing, js file will also keep growing unnecessarily.

Comment: Have you got any success in this?

Answer (score 2):

You may have a separate endpoint to check requested url, which returns page type like 'Product' or 'ProductList' and based on this result you can load more data

For example, let's say you have http://www.example.com/api/urlcheck

in your Router:

```
<Route exact path="/" component={ Home } />
<Route path="/:customPath" component={ Wrapper } />
```

in Wrapper

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state={
    componentName: null
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
  let pathname = this.props.location.pathname.substr(1)
  // alternatively you can get pathname from this.props.location.match.params.customPath
  fetch(/* send request to http://www.example.com/api/urlcheck with pathname */)
  .then((response)=>{ this.setState({componentName: response.componentName }) })
}

render (){
  const { componentName } = this.state

  if(componentName === 'Product') return <Product />
  else if(componentName === 'ProductList') return <ProductList />
}
```

in Product or ProductList components in a similar way you can request for specific set of data by id or any other key.

Keep in mind though, if SEO is a big piece, you most likely want to have server side rendering, which is not happening in the example above. `componentDidMount` renders only in browser and you'll have to replace that with componentWillMount (the only function in react lifecycle that runs on SSR).

SSR is a bit of a pain, especially with requests that are based on responses from other requests. Redux-saga makes life so much easier with this kind of stuff, so I'd recommend to go saga way in your case as well.

You can take a look at [react-saga-universal](https://github.com/max-gram/react-saga-universal) to quickly get up and running with saga and SSR.

Comment: According to [this scotch.io video on route params](https://scotch.io/courses/using-react-router-4/route-params) you can use `this.props.match.params` without the needing the `.location`