# Fetch React router paths from server

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a website with around 10,000 urls and these urls are basically cleaned by using server side Url Rewrite. Means, if I have a url like `http://example.com/best-cakes-in-sydney` it actually maps to `http://example.com/cakes?city=sydney`. Now what I want is to use `http://example.com/best-cakes-in-sydney` this url only in my React App.

But the problem with this is that, it is impossible to include any parameter in these urls, as they do not follow any specific pattern. Due to which I am forced to write down all these Urls in my react router config. But writing down 10,000 paths in my react router file does not seems like a good idea.

Please help me with any of the following:

1. If it is possible to generate react router config file then it could also work. In which on rendering of that file a AJAX request will go on server and it will pull all paths hence things are not hardcoded.
2. Is there any other way to tackle this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic paths in react router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45266423/dynamic-paths-in-react-router)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can send from your server the information about which component do you want to render on specific url.

If your request is `/best-cakes-in-sydney` your server will return a JSON like `{component: "cakes", city: "sydney", content: "...", ...}`

Then just pick the right component:

```
switch(response.component){
  case 'cakes': ...}
    <Cakes />
}
```

So basically you don't have to use Router, or just one global route for this.

Comment: This is exactly what I am thinking to implement

Comment: then just do it ;)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45266423/dynamic-paths-in-react-router/46079191#46079191